# changing code in kivy app while compiling with buildozer

Tags: python, kivy, apk, buildozer

I'm compiling my kivy app to an apk with buildozer.
The first apk bugged, so now I want to change some code.
Is it sufficient just to delete the apk in the bin folder, or do I have to delete the whole .buildozer folder, in order to make my changes apply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only change your python code, you don't need to delete anything.